# Writing Common.js modules in Typescript 2.7.2 - compilation questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am totally new to Typescript and Javascript as well, so this is undoubtedly a noobie question. I was looking at some Typescript 2.0 tutorials on writing modules. In the typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), the authors describe both the ES6 module import/export methods, and the CommonJS, AMD, and other import/export methods.

However, it seems that in my `tsconfig.json` I can specify which module handler I want to use when compiling: AMD, CommonJS, etc.

So my confusion is, can I write the import/exports using the standard ES6 statements with `import {}...`, and then those get converted to the appropriate CommonJS or RequireJS syntax on compilation? Or do I need to write the appropriate CommonJS/RequireJS, etc. syntax in typescript and then the compilation step will just use whatever I produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I write the import/exports using the standard ES6 statements with
>   import {}..., and then those get converted to the appropriate CommonJS
>   or RequireJS syntax on compilation?

Yes exactly, `import` and `export` are part of TypeScript language, and they are virtually identical to `import` and `export` in ES6.

TypeScript will compile them according to the combination of `module` and `target` settings in `tsconfig.json` - if `target` is `es6` or above (or if `module` itself is `es6`), `import` and `export` will remain in generated javascript, otherwise they will get converted to AMD or commonJS syntax.

Comment: Okay great. Wow that was just confusing me to no end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it affects the generated code, not how you should write your code.

As a learning exercise, I'd recommend looking at the output with each of the values: `None`, `CommonJS`, `AMD`, `System`, `UMD`, `ES6`, `ES2015` and `ESNext`.

Note that some compiler options aren't available in some configurations:

- `outFile` can only be used with `AMD` or `System`
- However `ES6` / `ES2015` may be used when targeting `ES5` or lower

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ES6 and ES2015 can only be used when targeting ES5 or lower". That has nothing to do with it. Also "ES6 === ES2015"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "may be used". I've updated my answer.

Comment: that's better but it's still not quite right. The `--target` and `--module` options don't depend on each other at all but this makes it sound like they do. Also es6 and es2015 are literally the same so you shouldn't list them separately as though there different formats. It's just that the nomenclature was changed. Just call it es2015 as that's the official name.

Comment: Its definitely confusing to think of `--target es3 --module esnext` but it's completely possible.